# How to change border style for classified data?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, classification

I would like to classify my layer according to two categories (for example year and type of land) and would like to show these classifications with a different colour of the border (for 'year') and fill (for 'type of land').

In the properties tab, after classifying my data, the only option of changing the colour of fill of the classified levels is available. Is there a way for me to use different borders to classify my data instead?

Comment: Have you tired using "Data Defined Override" to create rules for both rules and outline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to go for rulebased symbologies, e.g. based on the age of your area, and then build a sub-rule based on your type of land which is the same for all your "age-rules". That is quite a lot of work to have the same symbology everywhere, to be honest, but the outcome should be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer. Set the symbol layer type of the symbol selector as Outline: simple line, increase the thickness of the border (optional: just to better visualize the result), click ok and select the colour ramp you want your borders to be.
Sorry for not exploring more before I posted this question.

Comment: That's another way of doing it =)